# What does 'reflect' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> Once I was done optimizing the soil for my new low water consumption plan, I was ready to replace all my plants. I decided that the placement of all my plants would **reflect** the amount of water necessary to keep them alive.

What does 'reflect' mean here?

In chat, Damkerng suggested that it might be sense one in [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/reflect), "to show the existence or nature of something".  Jim Reynolds suggested that it might mean "correspond to; be in proportion with".  But I'm not sure, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: I believe **reflect**, in this case, would mean: in the *same relationship* as. Thus,  each plant would be placed in the *same relationship* as its need for water. For example, if a plant required a lot of water to stay alive it would be placed closer to the source of the water than one that required less. Therefore, each plant's placement would reflect the amount of water necessary to keep it alive.

Answer (score 5):

Here *reflect* means "be consonant with" or "in keeping with".  The plants will be arranged along a gradient, perhaps, from those needing the least water to those needing the most, with the water entering the soil so that it reaches the thirstiest plants first.